Model Assets for Stride using FAB
I have been creating Model Packs for both Unity and Unreal for some years now. I was wondering where the users of Stride obtain their assets from. Without a Store available, do you search the internet?
I am looking at potentially creating packs for Stride, for sale on FAB, which will include specific Materials for the Stride Engine.
Is this something the Stride Community/Users feel is worth doing at this time? I envisage creating a zip file, that contains folders of the various components for your scene, that can be simply drag and drop. Whilst the packs would be for Single License/Seat, with a EULA that means you cannot resell any packs of contents within directly, they can be used to incorporate in finished games and fully encapsulated to prevent exposure of the contents.
Is that something the Stride Community/Users see as useful? Feedback encouraged.

StackExchange is usually not the best place to do market research, since it largely falls into "opinion-based" territory, and the SE user base often includes only a narrow and non-representative slice of your target audience. I think you'd get a more accurate read on what the Stride userbase wants by posting in Stride community spaces instead.

Ah okay, thank you for the information. I have ventured onto the github stride forum with my enquiry.

Thanks for the information, I have posted there and already attracted some users :)
